# program become much slower using Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

My task is to compare data in two tables in a database to get the similarity,
say for example,if each table has 5 records, then i need to compare each record in table A to all the records in table B in order to get the similarity.
before i use single thread, if each table has 500 records, and it uses 4 minutes, right now i use 4 threads, it using half an hour! 
Here is my idea, i divide the first table into 4 tables, each stores part of the data, and then use 4 threads in the thread pool to start to compare, 
Here is the code, p1,p2 are the tables

```
Deduplication d = new Deduplication(pr2, threshold);

Func<List<ParentRecord>, List<ParentRecord>> method = d.Find;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    IEnumerable<ParentRecord> temp = pr1.Skip(i*part).Take(part);
    method.BeginInvoke(temp.ToList(), CallBackMethod, method);
}

private void CallBackMethod(IAsyncResult result)
{
    countThread++;

    var target = (Func<List<ParentRecord>, List<ParentRecord>>)result.AsyncState;
    List<ParentRecord> p=target.EndInvoke(result);
    lock (_locker)
    {
        records.AddRange(p);
    }
    if (countThread > 3)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new PopulateDelegate(PopulateGridView), new object[] { records });
    }
}

private void PopulateGridView(List<ParentRecord> p)
{ 
    dataGridViewParent.DataSource = p;
    dataGridViewDuplication.DataSource = null;
}
```

Sorry I am new to multithreading, so the idea may sound a bit stupid, i would highly appreciate if you can shed some light on, thanks.

Update

```
public List<ParentRecord> Find()
    {
        List<ParentRecord> result = new List<ParentRecord>();

        foreach (ParentRecord p1 in DataSource1)
        {
   List<DuplicateRecord> addedDuplicateRecords = new List<DuplicateRecord>();
            int num = 0;
            foreach (ParentRecord p2 in DataSource2)
            {

                //Check if these two rows have the same primary keys
                if (p1.PrimaryKey != p2.PrimaryKey)
                {
                    float similarity = 0F;
                    //Check if these two rows are the simply the same
                if (p1.CompareRow.ToUpper() == p2.CompareRow.ToUpper()) similarity = 1;
                    else similarity = GetSimilarity(p1.CompareRow, p2.CompareRow);
                    if (similarity >= threshold)
                    {
                        DuplicateRecord duplicateRecord = new DuplicateRecord();
                        duplicateRecord.PrimaryKey = p2.PrimaryKey;
                        duplicateRecord.CompareToRow = p2.CompareRow;
                        duplicateRecord.Similarity = similarity;
                        addedDuplicateRecords.Add(duplicateRecord);
                        num++;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Check if there are any reocrds meet the threadhold
            if (num > 0)
            {
                ParentRecord parentRecord = new ParentRecord();
                parentRecord.PrimaryKey = p1.PrimaryKey;
                parentRecord.CompareRow = p1.CompareRow;
                parentRecord.duplicateRecordList = addedDuplicateRecords;
                result.Add(parentRecord);
            } 
        }
        return result; 
    }

    private float GetSimilarity(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        float similarity = 1;


        MatchsMaker match = new MatchsMaker(obj1.ToString(), obj2.ToString());

        similarity = match.Score;


        return similarity;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the code for d.Find? this is where the problem has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what this does. 
I would try to solve the problem totally different, perhaps by using a well-crafted query or reading all data into memory rather than trying to step through a query from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are either deadlocking in the business tier and/or acquiring table-level locks at the database.

Off the top of my head, alternatives:

- two `DataReaders` being read side-by-side
- a database cursor (this could be a legitimate use)
- compare the record counts based on a series of `INNER JOIN`s
- a CTE (assuming you are using SQL Server)

If you are running performance tests with only 500 records, I can't imagine any of these approaches taking more than a few minutes.

Comment: but all the data are not in the database anymore, i copy them into different array list, will your guess still be the case?